# Javascript how to change JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON file

```
projectsJSON =  [
    {"name" : "Hotel"},
    {"name" : "Inventory"},
    {"name" : "Corp. Manager"}
];
```

And this code in `javascript.js

```
    let getProjects = projectsJSON
    getProjects.push({
        "name":name
    });
    projectsJSON = JSON.stringify(getProjects);`
```

My goal is to add a new object to `projectsJSON`,but this code is not working.When i print out `projectsJSON` it does show the added object,but file doesn't get changed.

Comment: "I have this JSON file" — That is not valid JSON.

Comment: You first example is not a JSON file. It's (presumably) JavaScript that assigns an array to the variable `projectsJSON`. *"but file doesn't get changed"* To do that you would have to write to the file system. And you would only be able to do that if your code runs in an environment that has access to the file system. If this is client side code then you actually have to write a server that accepts input from the client and writes to the file system.

Comment: Please have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object)

Comment: @Quentin what is wrong with it and how can i fix it?

Comment: You can't change a file with javascript. Not without using any filesystem features if it has. And that's an inline javascript object array. Not a file.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of [Read/write json from js to file on server (not server app)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4840727/218196)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using JavaScript running in the browser because it does not have access to read / modify the filesystem